# What is wrong with this Code Igniter mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables for storing information about a user. One is for authentication, the other is information the user will enter themselves. I am writing a model that will be used when the user interacts with this information. The following method is to return data for display and modification.

I need a query that will return 'email' and 'username' from $accounts_table and * from $profiles_table. I can't seem to get my head around the JOIN syntax though. I understand how joins work, but my queries throw sentax errors.

```
function get_userdata($id){
     $data = array();

     $this->db->get_where($this->profiles_table, array('user_id' => $id));
     $this->db->join($this->accounts_table.'.email', $this->accounts_table.'.id = '.$this->profiles_table.'.user_id');
     $data= $this->db->get();

     return $data;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: I've finally gotten the query doing what it should, but I had to resort to straight mySQL: 

    `function get($id) 
    { 
        $record=$this->db->query(' 
             SELECT '.$this->profiles_table.'.*, '.$this->accounts_table.'.username, '.$this->accounts_table.'.email 
             FROM '.$this->profiles_table.' LEFT JOIN '.$this->accounts_table.' 
             ON '.$this->profiles_table.'.user_id = '.$this->accounts_table.'.id 
             WHERE '.$this->profiles_table.'.user_id = '.$id); return $record->row_array(); }`

How would this chained up in CI notation... for the win?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of issues:

You should be using $this->db->where(), instead of $this->db->get_where().  get_where() executes the query immediately.

```
$this->db->get_where('user_id', $id);
```

Also the first argument of $this->db->join() should only be the table name, excluding the field.

```
$this->db->join($this->accounts_table, $this->accounts_table.'.id = '.$this->profiles_table.'.user_id');
```

And you're returning $data which is just an empty array().  You would need to pass the query results to $data like this:

```
$data = $record->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_where` executes the query.  So, your `join` is its own query, which doesn't work.

You need to break `get_where` into `where` and `from`.

Also, in MySQL, you `JOIN` a table, not a field.  If you want that field, add it to the `SELECT`.

```
$this->db->select($this->profiles_table.'.*');
$this->db->select($this->accounts_table.'.email,'.$this->accounts_table.'.username');
$this->db->from($this->profiles_table);
$this->db->where('user_id', $id);
$this->db->join($this->accounts_table, $this->accounts_table.'.id = '.$this->profiles_table.'.user_id');
$data = $this->db->get();
```

NOTE: `$this->db->get()` returns a [query object](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html), you need to use `result` or `row` to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've a mistake:

```
 $this->db->join($this->accounts_table.'.email', $this->accounts_table.'.id = '.$this->profiles_table.'.user_id');
```

First parameter should a table NOT a field: `$this->accounts_table.'.email'` is wrong IMHO. Or only a typo :)